# Can't upload to OneDrive Business using REST API

Tags: android, office365, retrofit, okhttp, onedrive

I am having issues uploading files to my OneDrive Business account in Android.

I am using the upload API described here (simple and resumable both doesn't work for me): 
https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload.htm

Everything else works fine. I can browse, create folders, delete, rename, download files. I use the same implementation for regular OneDrive and that works without issues. I have also tested with official OneDrive Android app and there upload works, so it doesn't seem to be a permissions issue with my OneDrive Office 365 account.

I am using Retrofit/OkHttp.

This is the log from the query:

```
OkHttp: --> PUT https://<tenantname>-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/root:/pricelist.pdf:/content HTTP/1.1
OkHttp: Content-Type: application/pdf
OkHttp: --> END PUT

OkHttp: <-- 500 Internal Server Error https://<tenantname>-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/root:/pricelist.pdf:/content (831ms)
OkHttp: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
OkHttp: Expires: Mon, 01 Feb 2016 22:09:26 GMT
OkHttp: Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 22:09:26 GMT
OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
OkHttp: X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
OkHttp: X-SP-SERVERSTATE: ReadOnly=0
OkHttp: ODATA-VERSION: 4.0
OkHttp: SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 92
OkHttp: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
OkHttp: SPRequestGuid: e5e45f9d-80fa-3000-9580-b34e009cc4be
OkHttp: request-id: e5e45f9d-80fa-3000-9580-b34e009cc4be
OkHttp: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
OkHttp: X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
OkHttp: MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.4921
OkHttp: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
OkHttp: X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
OkHttp: P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
OkHttp: Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 22:09:25 GMT
OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1455660569448
OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1455660570267
OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
TransferFileTask: Exception when transferring file
HttpException: OneDrive error: code = -1, System.IO.IOException, message = I/O error occurred.
```

What happens is that I always get a 500 internal server error with the same error body as seen above. As stated the exact same upload code works for ordinary OneDrive.

I have tried adding many different headers, like Content-Length, Host, Cache-Control etc. but nothing seems to make a difference. What is not seen is a Authorization header which is of course correct and works for all other requests.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was caused by missing Content-Length header. This was omitted by mistake. Regulear OneDrive apparently didn't care and worked fine, but OneDrive Business requires the header.